# excluding elements to be scraped

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to exclude certain elements from a list.

on the page http://www.persimmonhomes.com/rooley-park-10126 there are the elements I want to scrap which are (div class="housetype js-filter-housetype") and there are those I don't want to scrap which are (div class="housetype js-filter-housetype" style="display: none;")

the html looks something like:

```
<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype"> 
<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype"> 
<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype"> 
<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype">
<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype"> 
<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype" style="display: none;">
<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype" style="display: none;">
```

I am trying to write code to exclude the div class="housetype js-filter-housetype" style="display: none;".

My current code to do this is:

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.persimmonhomes.com/rooley-park-10126",
]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]/div[4]'):
        item = PersimmonItem()
        item['housetypeheading'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="houses-list js-scrollable js-filterable js-houselist"]//*[not(@style="display: none;")]/h2[@class="housetype__heading"]').extract()
        yield item
```

so far, this does not work.  It just scraps all the elements whether or not it has the part (style="display: none;").  I have also tried the [not(contains(@style, "display: none;"))] - but so far no luck.

may i ask for any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore all with a style attribute:

```
"//div[@class='housetype js-filter-housetype' and not(@style)]"
```

Or that particular style, just use `and`:

```
"//div[@class='housetype js-filter-housetype' and not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))]"
```

Comment: thank you for that.  I can see how that should work, but in this case it is not allowing the code to ignore the div class="housetype js-filter-housetype" style="display: none;"  In fact, it is almost as if the webpage does not recognise that it has "style" as an attribute

Comment: let me test it out on the page in  bit

Comment: @nevster, no div on that page has `<div class="housetype js-filter-housetype" style="display: none;">` there are 9 with the class but none have a style attribute, I also see only three `style="display: none"` on the page in other tags and none have a trailing `;`

Comment: ah, it must be the way my chrome is inspecting the page.  For sure you are right though given the "style" is not in any way recognised when I try and latch onto it